# How to add categorical variable to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Im working in a World Happiness Report project that includes datasets from 2015 to 2019. I concatenated them into a final dataframe to get average of parameters (economy, health, etc.) for every country across that time span. But what I forgot to add was the respective region that the country is in (ej: England - Western Europe). How could I add the 'Region' column to my final dataframe and to be sure that that region matches with its respective country?

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm pretty sure it is simple to correct this. Would you have an example of your data ? I would suggest merging with joins using a primary key

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: I already attached an image.

Comment: @JesusIvanVerdugo, please change your image to a text value.

Comment: @JesusIvanVerdugo, i have provided two options. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

You may want to do something like this:

```
df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(region_df.set_index('Country')['Region'])
```

Or you can also use merge statement. The assumption is that for each country, you have a region that it can map to.

```
df = pd.merge(df,region_df,how='left',on = ['Country'])
```

Make sure you have indexed both on Country before you merge to get the optimized response.

**data setup**

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['Country','Happiness Score','Other_fields']
d = [['Denmark', 7.5460,1.25],
     ['Norway',7.5410,1.50],
     ['Finland',7.5378,1.85]]

region_cols = ['Country','Region']
region_data = [['Denmark','R1'],['Norway','R2'],['Finland','R3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d, columns = c)
region_df = pd.DataFrame(data = region_data, columns = region_cols)
```

Based on the lookup DataFrame, you can do a map to check for Country and assign Region to df.

```
df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(region_df.set_index('Country')['Region'])
print (df)
```

Your result will be as follows:

Base DataFrame:

```
   Country  Happiness Score  Other_fields
0  Denmark           7.5460          1.25
1   Norway           7.5410          1.50
2  Finland           7.5378          1.85
```

Lookup DataFrame:

```
   Country Region
0  Denmark     R1
1   Norway     R2
2  Finland     R3
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
   Country  Happiness Score  Other_fields Region
0  Denmark           7.5460          1.25     R1
1   Norway           7.5410          1.50     R2
2  Finland           7.5378          1.85     R3
```

Comment: In region_data would I need to match all 150+ countries with its respective nation?

Comment: You need to create the lookup table with all the 150+ countries. You need to create this first, then run it to get the match.